# Uploading a video caus $_POST/$_FILES to be empty

Tags: php, html, css, file-upload

I am trying to upload the image and video in my project, but when I tried to upload video it returns an empty array for `$_POST` and `$_FILES` both.
If I try to upload an image, the same code is working fine. The code I have used is below:

```
extract($_POST);
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$target_dir = $upload_dir['basedir'].'/mediauploads/';
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if($upd)
{
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

    if($imageFileType != "mp4" && $imageFileType != "wmv" && $imageFileType != "avi" && $imageFileType != "mov" && $imageFileType != "3gp" && $imageFileType != "mpeg" && $imageFileType != "jpg")
    {
        echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
    } else {
        $video_path=$_FILES['fileToUpload']['name'];  
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"],$target_file);
        echo "uploaded ";
    } 
}
```

Upload video form:

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<table border="1" style="padding:10px">
    <tr>
        <Td>Upload  Video</td>
    </tr>

    <Tr>
        <td><input type="file" name="fileToUpload"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <td><input type="submit" value="Uplaod Video" name="upd"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: What's  $upd, in your question it's not set so that first condition will fail. Never mind, it's the submit button and extract, I would change that ... it's hard to read and pointless using extract on one field, also your translating post keys to variable names, which is probably not the best practice in the world..

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (isset($_FILES["stPic"]["name"]) && $_FILES["stPic"]["tmp_name"] != ""){
        $fileName = $_FILES["stPic"]["name"];
        $fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["stPic"]["tmp_name"];
        $fileType = $_FILES["stPic"]["type"];
        $fileSize = $_FILES["stPic"]["size"];
        $fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["stPic"]["error"];

     if (!preg_match("/.(gif|jpg|png|mp4|3gp|wmw|avi|mkv)$/i", $fileName) ) {
    echo "File Format Not Suppoted";
}else{
$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "video/$fileName");
if ($moveResult != true) {
        echo 'file not upload';
        exit();
    }
else{
//You run sql query 
echo 'Uploaded';
}


}
}
```